# spring cloud contract - Feign Clients

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, spring-cloud-contract

Using Spring cloud contract to verify contract between my producer and consumer. In my consumer controller, I am using Feign client to call another micro-service method to get some data. But now in spring cloud contract making that stub call for this micro-service is impossible.

Using Spring Cloud with Netflix OSS.

Config-service and eureka is up. Now I installed my producer locally at port 8090. Consumer using Feign clients to call producer to get some data. Now I am getting 500 error. It is showing that URL not found. The closest match is /ping. I believe Feign client is unable to mock, it is somehow trying to connect with eureka not from the locally installed producer. Can you help me on it.

Any example or any idea will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, here is my JUnit test that does it (`ParticipantsService` uses a Feign Client)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.ryanjbaxter.spring.cloud:ocr-participants:+:stubs"}, workOffline = true)
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class OcrRacesApplicationTestsBase {

    @Autowired
    protected ParticipantsService participantsService;

    private List<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<>();


    //Hack to work around https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/156
    static {
        System.setProperty("eureka.client.enabled", "false");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.failFast", "false");
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.participants = new ArrayList<>();
        this.participants.add(new Participant("Ryan", "Baxter", "MA", "S", Arrays.asList("123", "456")));
        this.participants.add(new Participant("Stephanie", "Baxter", "MA", "S", Arrays.asList("456")));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        this.participants = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        List<Participant> participantList = participantsService.getAllParticipants();
        assertEquals(participants, participantList);
    }
}
```

Comment: It did't worked. I tried the same. I updated the question. Can you have a look

Comment: You dont need Eureka or the config server up in order for contract to work.  Based on the fact that it cant find a contract that matches it seems like maybe there is a difference between the request being send and your contract.  Could you perhaps post the contract and the request being sent?

Comment: Update: I think that starting with Dalston this got fixed!